# Create array of object from different promise factory method?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in my controller

```
 dashboardFactory.totalCustomer().then(function (response){
    $scope.totalCustomer = response.data.count;
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

 dashboardFactory.totalPartner().then(function (response){
    $scope.totalPartner = response.data.count;
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });


//below passed to html
$scope.charts = [{
  color: pieColor,
  description: 'Total Partner',
  stats: $scope.totalPartner,
  icon: 'person',
}, {
  color: pieColor,
  description: 'Jumlah Konsumen',
  stats: $scope.totalCustomer,
  icon: 'money',
}];
```

The above code result in empty, this is because $scope.charts created while promise not yet resolved?

How I can create array of object from promise result if every object have property which get from different promise factory method? so the rendered page is not empty.

The above example is 2 object, imagine if I have 10 or more object each object get from different promise factory method.

Any explanation appreciated as I'm new in angular.

Comment: regardless of how many chart objects are there in the array. is the index of each of the object fixed or they can change?

Comment: @Sagi_Avinash_Varma doesn't matter because chart object will rendered with ng-repeat :D thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use [$q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all):

```
var totalCustomerPromise = dashboardFactory.totalCustomer().then(function (response){
  return response.data.count;
});

var totalPartnerPromise = dashboardFactory.totalPartner().then(function (response){
  return response.data.count;
});

$q.all({
  totalCustomer: totalCustomerPromise,
  totalPartner: totalPartnerPromise
}).then(function(result) {
  $scope.charts = [{
    color: pieColor,
    description: 'Total Partner',
    stats: result.totalPartner,
    icon: 'person',
  }, 
  {
    color: pieColor,
    description: 'Jumlah Konsumen',
    stats: result.totalCustomer,
    icon: 'money',
  }];
});
```

Or, if you don't care that your objects in the scope don't have a vaid stats until the promises are resolved, just initialize their stats property from within the callbacks passed to then():

```
dashboardFactory.totalCustomer().then(function (response){
  $scope.charts[1].stats = response.data.count;
});
```